# How to send files to Django REST Framework from React?

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I need to send arbitrary (e.g. `xls`) files from React-based frontend to Django REST Framework backend.

Googled and tried many code variants for couple of hours, none of them worked completely.

Here are essential parts of code:

1. React

1.1 Form input field

```
<input
    type="file"
    multiple={true}
    accept=".xls,.xlsx,.csv,.txt"
    onChange={this.handleFilesChosen}
/>
```

1.2 handleFilesChosen

```
    handleFilesChosen = event => {
        this.setState({
            files: event.target.files
        });
    }
```

1.3 Upload click handler (`authHeader` is function substituting Authorization Bearer token)

```
    handleUploadClick = event => {
        let formData = new FormData();
        for (let file of this.state.files) {
            formData.append('files', file);
        }
        const csrf = this.getCookie('csrftoken');
        fetch(`${API_BASE_PATH}/load-input-data/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: authHeader({contentType: 'multipart/form-data', csrf: csrf}),
            body: formData,
        })
        .then(result => result.json())
        .catch(error => error);
    }
```

2. DRF View

```
class LoadInputDataView(APIView):
    parser_class = (MultiPartParser,)

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print(request.data)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I selected simple txt file (to make debugging easy, binary will go later) with `hello world` content, uploaded it and get `<QueryDict: {}>` in Django `runserver` console.

If I look at Chrome network tab, I see following empty request payload instead of real file content:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryYw6ABRFkvxatzHqi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="foo.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain


------WebKitFormBoundaryYw6ABRFkvxatzHqi--
```

Tried to remove `contentType` header - got 400 error with message `JSON parse error` (browser substitutes JSON contentType header automatically).

I'm stuck. Could anybody guide me?

Comment: Look at `axios` package. This may be also helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uyei2iDA4Hs

Comment: did you try print(request.body) ?

Comment: @BobWhite, looks better, now I got `b'------WebKitFormBoundary9XymQXg2cF659SKh\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="foo.txt"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nhello world\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary9XymQXg2cF659SKh--\r\n'`. How to correctly strip boundaries and extract content now? I understand that I could use regexps, but maybe there are some built in method?

Comment: i got it. your are using formdata you should get it by using request.POST.get('files') also try request.FILES

Comment: `request.POST.get('files')` - `None`, `request.FILES` - `<MultiValueDict: {}>`

Comment: @BobWhite, found solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57379004/1927853 and now `request.FILES` work

Answer (score 1):

Found solution. I should not set `Content-Type` header manually, it is set automatically with `boundary` option. Now Django's `request.FILES` work too and I could work with uploaded files from backend using code like:

```
class ParseInputDataView(APIView):
    parser_class = (MultiPartParser,)
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, controller_id, format=None):
        for file_entry in request.FILES.getlist('files'):
            uploaded_file_name = file_entry.name
            uploaded_file_content = file_entry.read()
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to maintain uniformity in the API and send the image within JSON.

**In React:**

```
const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      var blocks = reader.result.split(";");
      const realData = blocks[1].split(",")[1];
      setImage(realData);
    };
    reader.onerror = (error) => console.error(error);
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
  };

 const onSaveHandler = () => {
    fetch(`/url`, {
        method: "post",
        credentials: "include", // send cookie with auth
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-CSRFToken": document.getElementById("csrf-token").value,
        }
        body: JSON.stringify({imageData: image}),
     });
 }

return(
 <div>
      <input
        onChange={handleImageChange}
        id="logo"
        type="file"
        multiple="false"
        accept="image/*"
      />
      <button onClick={onSaveHandler}>
        SAVE
      </button>
 </div>);
```

**In Django (DRF):**

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      # override create method
      def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        image_path = "whatever.jpg"
        print('save image on disk: ' + image_path)
        with open(image_path, "wb") as fh:
            fh.write(base64.b64decode(request.data.get("imageData")))
        return super().create(request)
```